# How can I find out if elements of an array match any elements of another array?

Tags: perl

if I have a hash

```
my %foo = ( foo => 1, bar => 1 );
```

I want to check if any key of `%foo` is in a comparison array (and obviously keys %foo is just an array ). I keep thinking some weird syntax that does't exist like.

```
my @cmp0 = qw( foo baz    );
my @cmp1 = qw( baz blargh );

if keys %foo in @cmp0 # returns true because key foo is in the array
if keys %foo in @cmp1 # returns false because no key in foo is an element of cmp1
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: `keys %foo` is a *list* and very much *not* an array. An array is a Perl variable which can take the place of a list, but it can also do a lot of things an array can't do. See [What is the difference between a list and an array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3F)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils) has a function called `any` that uses a syntax similar to `grep`, but stops its internal loop the first time the criteria are met.  The advantage to this behavior is that far fewer iterations will be required (assuming random distribution of intersections).

An additional advantage of `any` is code clarity: It is named for what it does.  Perl Best Practices discourages using `grep` in Boolean context because the assumed use for `grep` is to return a list of elements that match.  It works in Boolean context, but the intent of the code is less clear to a reader than `any`, which is designed specifically for Boolean usage.

It is true that `any` adds a dependency on List::MoreUtils.  However, List::MoreUtils is one of those modules that is so ubiquitous, it is highly likely to already be installed.

Here's an example:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw( any );

my %foo = ( foo => 1, bar => 1 );

my @cmp0 = qw( foo baz    );
my @cmp1 = qw( baz blargh );

print "\@cmp0 and %foo have an intersection.\n" 
    if any { exists $foo{$_} } @cmp0;

print "\@cmp1 and %foo have an intersection.\n"
    if any { exists $foo{$_} } @cmp1;
```

Another option is the `~~` [Smart Match Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator), which became available in Perl 5.10.0 and newer.  It could be used like this:

```
my %foo = ( foo => 1, bar => 1 );

my @cmp0 = qw( foo baz    );
my @cmp1 = qw( baz blargh );

print "\@cmp0 and %foo have an intersection.\n" if @cmp0 ~~ %foo;

print "\@cmp1 and %foo have an intersection.\n" if @cmp1 ~~ %foo;
```

With smartmatch, you eliminate the List::MoreUtils dependency in favor of a minimum Perl version dependency.  It's up to you to decide whether the code is as clear as `any`.

Comment: +1 for knowing what the smart match operator does without looking it up.

Comment: Perl6::Junction also has a helpful any() function.

Comment: Although `List::MoreUtils::any` doesn't require the full iteration, my performance benchmarks show that it is 10x slower than `grep` on my machine, even with XS. `List::Util::first` is a little faster, but still not as fast as `grep`.

Comment: It's going to depend a lot on the size of the list, and the distribution of the intersections.  Imagine a list of 10,000 elements, with one intersection at the 5,000th slot.  `grep` would consume 10,000 iterations, `any` would consume 5,000.  It might be an interesting discussion as a meditation over at PerlMonks, where more in-depth discussion is encouraged.

Comment: a list of size 10k? if I were dealing with a list that size I'd hope I'd be using something like SQL to deal with it... I'm just trying not to write [assembler](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10973409/206466) for like 10, 20 options in some backwards compatibility code.

Comment: @xenoterracide: In a situation where `grep` is faster, there are going to be so few elements that it doesn't matter.  In a situation where `any` is faster, it still may not matter, but if it does, `any` may save time because it would probably terminate after fewer iterations.  But there's another advantage to `any`: Code clarity.  If you want to know if there are "any" of this in that, use `any`.  If you want to know all of the "this's" in "that", use grep.  PBP.  ...or forget about `any` vs `grep` and just use Smartmatch. :)

Answer (score 5):

The tidiest way to write this is to use `grep` together with the `exists` operator.

This code

```
my %foo = ( foo => 1, bar => 1 );

my @cmp0 = qw( foo baz    );
my @cmp1 = qw( baz blargh );

print "YES 0\n" if grep { exists $foo{$_} } @cmp0;
print "YES 1\n" if grep { exists $foo{$_} } @cmp1;
```

gives this output

```
YES 0
```

Answer (score 5):

`grep` is a good idea, and probably the cleanest. You can however also use the [logical OR assignment operator `||=`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators):

```
my $found;
$found ||= exists $foo{$_} for @cmp1;
```

Answer (score 1):

These are simple **set operations**.

```
use strictures;
use Set::Scalar qw();
⋮
my $foo = Set::Scalar->new(keys %foo);
$foo->intersection(Set::Scalar->new(@cmp0))->size; # 1
$foo->intersection(Set::Scalar->new(@cmp1))->size; # 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There are - as usual - more ways to solve this. You could do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;

my %hash = ( foo => 1 , bar => 1 ) ;
my %cmp = ( cmp0 => [ qw(foo baz) ] ,
            cmp1 => [ qw(baz blargh) ] ) ;

my @hash_keys = keys %hash ;
foreach my $compare ( keys %cmp ) {
  my %tmp ;
  # Generate a temporary hash from comparison keys via hash slice
  @tmp{@{$cmp{$compare}}} = undef ;
  INNER:
  foreach my $hash_key ( @hash_keys ) {
    if( exists $tmp{$hash_key} ) {
      printf "Key '%s' is part of '%s'.\n" , $hash_key , $compare ;
      last INNER ;
    }
  }
}
```

This gives:

```
Key 'foo' is part of 'cmp0'.
```

Comment: Is this an example of "Real programmers can write assembly code in any language!"?

Comment: No, its an example for "Tired? Go to bed and don't answer SO questions".